# if else statement returning wrong answer

Tags: java, maven, conditional-statements, maven-2, maven-plugin

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class orOperator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(" This code is to check you are eligible or not");
        Scanner buddha2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your nationality");
        String nationality = buddha2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("you are " + nationality);
        if (nationality == "indian") {
            System.out.println("you are eligible to join the indian army");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your are not eligible to join the army");
        }
    }

}
```

///the else part is returning answer not the if part//
///the motto is to take the nationality as input and then will be able to get the result out as the nationality ///

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (nationality.equals("indian"))
```

When using "==" it checks for the referential equality of two vars meaning if they reference the same object or not.

Comment: Thanks Lucas ,It is working fine .but what can be the scenario that it is not taking the == operator .do u think its and issue with the version.

Comment: No, its just that when using strings you cannot use the = operator.

Comment: ok Thanks lucas

Comment: The operator `==` checks for instance identity not for content identity ... (there are some exceptions of that, but they are not relevant here at the moment)..